# MySQL query to substring length check up and sum respective substrings to one

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a SQL query to check if column each NAIC code value is 3 if yes then sum all output values having the same 3 digit NAIC code

```
SELECT ni.NAICS,
ncio.outputValue,
IF( NAICS =SUBSTR(ni.NAICS,0,3), SUM(ncio.outputValue), NULL )

                            FROM 
                                    nwk_company_industry_output ncio,
                                    nwk_industry ni,
                                    nwk_company nc 

                            WHERE
                                    ni.NAICS = ncio.company_id
                            ORDER BY 

                                    NAICS
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: the heading and the details both are question, the sample code doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you provided the join condition is correct (ni.NAICS=ncio.company_id)

```
SELECT ni.NAICS,
       sum(ncio.outputValue) as sum_outputValue
  FROM nwk_company_industry_output ncio,
       nwk_industry ni
--        nwk_company nc   (doesn't appear to be needed)
 WHERE length(ni.NAICS) = 3
   AND ni.NAICS = ncio.company_id
-- (join condition here if new_company is needed)
 GROUP BY ni.NAICS;
```